# Overflow not triggering on expanding div (jQuery page)

Tags: jquery, html, overflow

I am making a chat page with jQuery with the send button on the bottom and messages going upwards. I want the div containing the messages to overflow when it reaches the top of the page, but it continues to expand.

Here is the HTML/jQuery:

```
<div style= "margin-top:0px;" data-role="page" id="politics">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#home" data-icon="home">Home</a><h1>Chat about politics!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="placeBottom" data-role="content">
            <div id="outputPolitics" style="margin-top:10px"></div>
            <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="Enter chat here" id="inputPolitics">
            <button id="buttonSendPolitics" class="btn">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    #outputPolitics
{
    font-family: "Times new roman", Times, serif;
    background-color: #ebe8bd;
    height: 100%
    overflow:scroll;
}

.thread
{
    position: relative;
}

.placeBottom
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 90%;

}
```

I am guessing this has something to to with my choice of position on the divs. I found this "placeBottom" trick on the internet and is this the hickup?

Comment: a jsfiddle would probably help everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple, your `div` have no height, so it has no limit.

If you want a fixed height on the `div` just set it like `height : 100%;`

Else if you want the `div` to exepend with the text and when it reach some point, the scrollbar work, just set a `max-height: 100%;` on your `div` and `height:auto` wich is the default value.

Note that you can change those value for what you need. It can be `px`, `em` or whatever you want!

Comment: I set the height to 100% in my outputPolitics div but it keeps expanding forever. Funny thing is if I set the height of this div to 200px overflow triggers but messages is now going downwards! I am confused!

Comment: The scrolling thing is because that's how browser work, you need to code after adding text to the div like `$('#yourDiv').scrollTop(X value to scroll to bottom)`